# Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:62535', transport: 'socket' on intellij idea CE. I can't debug my program. Any suggestions?

Tags: intellij-idea

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63073', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63073', transport: 'socket'

Comment: you may get it if you declared mistakenly 2 public static void main method.

Comment: Check if you have clicked on "Mute Breakpoints" button in intellij

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. I noticed that the drop-down menu wasn't set on app. Check this out:

[image: Configuration Example]

Comment: @user6683868 ... I don't have that small drop-down on screen.  Do you know what property it reflects?

Comment: This should be - maybe - the `working directory`

Answer (score 9):

Which line did you put breakpoint? Suppose you have the following snippet:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int res = add(5, 8);
        System.out.println(res);

    }

    public static int add(int a, int b)
    {
        int c=a+b;
        return c;
    }
```

When I put the breakpoint the line that has { under the add method. I got the very same error as you. If I put the breakpoint to the line int c=a+b;, the debugger works as expected. It's annoying, this is the solution I could come up.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is very simple to resolve. Click on debug again and in the right-hand corner, you should see a tool bar.  There's an icon that looks like two red break points overlapping.  Click on that.  It will pop open a menu under any exception.  Please ensure that Enabled, Suspend, All, Condition, log message to console and log evaluated expression are all checked.

Answer (score 4):

The above message shows that JVM started and has stopped successfully.

Now what you are expecting is to halt on the breakpoint which you have applied in your program but you can't achieve that because you might have clicked on **"Mute Breakpoints"** button and are trying to debug a code which does not display anything on console.

Since all breakpoints are muted, your program does not halt on the expected line.

Answer (score 3):

Probably your program has a bug before your first breakpoint, or the program never reaches that breakpint.

Answer (score 2):

Just find your projectApplication and then Run Debug on anything you want.

For Example see bellow

```java
SpringBootApplication
public class BitApplication {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BitApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BitApplication .class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a variety of things, but likely you're hitting an exception before any break points hit. Do you see an exception in your console?

An exception might look like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1):

**Mute Breakpoints** this worked well for me

Answer (score 1):

This problem happen when another program is using that port, so you can change port in spring, and use another port. You just need to type this simple code in your program.

```
System.setProperty("server.port", "4000");
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm0zb.png)

Answer (score 1):

You see this message because there is nothing to debug at current marker. You can check whether your marker is in the correct place or not.
also, you might be trying to debug another class that has no markers or empty you can check your run configuration or run the the class that you want debug  from project files.

Answer (score 1):

restarting IDEA helped me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

I needed to delete the out files that had been created by IntelliJ from my previous debugging. A simple right click and delete on the "out" folder under your project tab should do the trick. Then compile your program again.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for a lot of reasons. In my case the root cause was found in the hibernate entities I was using. I needed to use couple of attributes in the entity domain that were not part of related db table. When I annotated these attributes with Transient. The spring boot application started just fine.

Example:

Entity that caused error:

```
class ErrorDomain{
    @Column(name = "db_prop_available")
    private String dbPropAvailable;

    private String dbPropNotAvailable;
}
```

Entity update to fix the issue:

```
class OkDomain{
    @Column(name = "db_prop_available")
    private String dbPropAvailable;

    @Transient   //javax.persistence
    private String dbPropNotAvailable;
}
```

This is one of the reasons for the original error you posted. But I just wanted to comment if anybody has a similar case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error that led me directly to this thread.

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57662', transport: 'socket'
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd0e3122a0, pid=6908, tid=0x0000000000000594
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig75icd64.dll+0xd22a0]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\UserNamed\IdeaProjects\supercoolproject\android\assets\hs_err_pid6908.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57662', transport: 'socket'
```

By reading the unusual text between

> Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63073', transport: 'socket'

and

> Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63073', transport: 'socket'

I could locate a real stack trace at:

C:\Users\UserNamed\IdeaProjects\supercoolproject\android\assets\hs_err_pid6908.log

Which led me to trap my error precisely.

**UPDATE, evening**
YMMV, I just had a similar probelm, left the debugger running while reading a paper and Java notified me via popup there was a problem but IntelliJ gave me even less to go on. The obligatory:

> Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63073', transport: 'socket'
>
> Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63073', transport: 'socket'

Then something about it having closed with a 255 error code. I tried recreating the error, because it's easier than tracing my memory leak, and it worked, here is the Java error:

[image: Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working]

I'm suspicious of companies (IdeaC) pushing yet another Java binary. I clicked debug this time and got:

[image: Visual Studio Just-in-Time Debugger]

I can't say for certain but this appears a weakness in IntelliJ 2018. My code has got bigger too, but updates seem to bring more version conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to re-enable debugger mode. Breakpoints were muted.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ to solve this I found the following, that the class name wasn't linked to the file name

alt+shift+f10 
right
Edit

The main class was only the name of the file I had as a class
ImageLabel

[image: Before Changing]

[image: Clicking on the 3 dots and selecting the class name I found this to be selected]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem + message `Could not find or load main class`.

It was a project on Scala with SBT.

How I solved this one:

1. Run my project via SBT like this: `sbt my-project/run`
2. Stopped it (Ctrl+C)
3. Run debug -- it works again.

Answer (score 0):

For Maven+Spring projects, I was debugging using the Spring Boot Configuration and didn't realize that the Maven configuration was already running. Shutting Maven off and restarting did the trick.

Also if you use Docker do a `docker ps -a` to see if your container is running.

Comment: How to off maven?

Answer (score 0):

maven clean followed by maven install worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had commented my all test cases and then I was trying to run test cases in debug mode. So obviously there is nothing to run. So I was getting below message.
Once check if the run you are trying to do all is OK.

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:65223', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:65223', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

Try re import project into intellij
I had the same problem when I wanted to import eclipse project into intellij ide and reimporting solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that you have missing environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue I was getting in my Intenlliz and the root cause for that issue was application.yaml file.

Please validate properties value should have space:

Error with bad configuration:
[wrong configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdA1t.png)

Expected configuration should have space between key and value after “:”
[right configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrzKE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and took me a while to figure out what was wrong.
I was supplying some VM args in the tomcat config panel and one of the vm arg had a new line character. So check that the configs are correct. Once when I removed those special characters, it booted fine. wish u all good luck.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsl9b.png)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when another program uses that port, so you can change the port in the spring and use another port. You need to type this simple code in your application.properties.

```
server.port=8080
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First mark a debug market on the left statement index panel, from where you want to debug the specific program. after that this will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the scope in the dependency of tomcat that caused the problem. when removing it it run without stopping.

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and fixed it by :

Adding activity name in App> manifest> androidManifest.XML

Answer (score 0):

Run Java Main class it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, redis was causing problems like that "***Redis health check failed , Unable to connect to Redis***" and when I tried to enable it, I did not get any errors from spring boot and it suddenly shut down.

```
management:
  health:
    redis:
      enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

- My issue is about run wrong main method.
- I am running main method in test package.
- Then, I run application of spring boot project with main method in test package so that it makes error.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35683447)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I went to the device Manager and

1. Wiped Data +
2. Cold Boot.

This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).