# IntelliJ compiler not executing, showing error

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the following code running in my machine and every time I run the code, the compiler does not execute and exit without running the code. The code is running in IntelliJ and its Java language. Test data is in the excel sheet and in .ftl file with schema validator.

```
 @Test(timeOut = Cons.TESTCASE_TIMEOUT, groups = {Group.FULL_REGRESSION}, dataProvider = "getDataFromDirectExcel")
public void saveAsDraftPortfolio(Scenario scenario) {

    String bodyTemplate = scenario.getParam("postBodyPDOP");
    String portfolioId = scenario.getParam("portfolioId");
    String folderID = scenario.getParam("folderId");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

            String api = scenario.getParam("api" + i);
            scenario.setParam("api" + i, api);
            if ((api == null) || (StringUtils.isBlank(api))) {
                return;
            }

            if (StringUtils.isBlank(portfolioId) || "null".equals(portfolioId)) {
                portfolioId = null;
            }

            Map<String, Object> templateArgs = new HashMap<>();
            templateArgs.put("portfolioId", portfolioId);
            String portfolioBody = TemplateUtil.getInstance().loadTemplate(PORTFOLIO_EDIT_BODY_PATH + bodyTemplate, templateArgs);

            // Call createDraftPortfolio API
            ValidatableResponse response = Api.of(api, scenario).set(scenario.params)
                    .body(portfolioBody)
                    .call();

            // Extract and validate the response
            int statusCode = response.extract().statusCode();
            String responseBodyStr = response.extract().response().getBody().asString();

            //Check that the status code was 200
            Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, 200, "The API call to create a portfolio did not return HTTP 200.");

            //Schema validator
            String schemaFile = scenario.getParam("expectedSchemaFile");
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(schemaFile)) {
                new SchemaValidator(schemaFilePath, schemaFile).checkSchema(response);
            }

            // Parse the response body
            String message = JsonPath.with(responseBodyStr).get("message");
            newPortfolioId = JsonPath.with(responseBodyStr).get("id");
            String expectedFolderId = JsonPath.with(responseBodyStr).get("folderId");

            // Store newPortfolioId in the scenario object
            scenario.setParam("newPortfolioId", newPortfolioId);

            // Check that the response
            String expectedResult = scenario.getParam("expectedResult");

            Assert.assertEquals(message, expectedResult, unexpectedErrorMsg);
            Assert.assertEquals(folderID, expectedFolderId, "folderIDs are different. Test failed.");

            Assert.assertTrue(newPortfolioId != null && !newPortfolioId.isEmpty(), "The new portfolio ID is null or empty.");

        }
```

The debug shows the following error :

```
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60245', transport: 'socket'
```

Any idea why this is happening? I have cloned the repo again but didnt work. The weird part of this is that all other test cases are running correctly. Only this one is not executing.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37781970/disconnected-from-the-target-vm-address-127-0-0-162535-transport-socket

Comment: This is not an error, refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html. Don't forget to place a breakpoint.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Where should I place a breakpoint?

Comment: @RobertBain I looked at that thread before posting. The suggestions doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: Place a breakpoint where you want your code to stop. The message you get is just the app execution finished. What do you expect to see instead?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes. I did that. Its in the original post. The code doesn't reach the breakpoint. Even the breakpoint is at line number 1, the error is the same.

Comment: What code do you run? This test, or some other configuration? Provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder The code is the same code I am trying to run. The files that are associated with this is test data, that includes the following : saveAsDraftPortfolio.xlsx, For security reasons, I can not include the actual test data in this post.

Comment: Post the full command line that is executed by the IDE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254733/discussion-between-bubbles-and-crazycoder).

Comment: Posted in the chat

Comment: I just send this code to another friend. He is not able to execute on the same environment as well. Getting the same error message. There is something wrong in the code itself.

Comment: As explained, this is not an error message, it's just a status message that the process has finished and the debugger is disconnected from the process. It does not explain anything.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging deeper into the code, I have found out there was an issue in my test data file. The code was completely fine. The test data, however, had a clause

```
where if 
first 5 columns are not testid, test case, test description, environment and case priority 
   then 
runs ignoreCase method
```

which basically ignores the testcases. In our case, it is what it was doing as I added "invalid" column (6th) in the 2nd column. I believe the framework I am working on is quite old and needs to handle this type of scenarios better way. I will add supportive code to make sure this doesn't happen in the future.