# Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'javadebug', transport: 'shared memory'

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-s3, intellij-idea

While debuging program following  error is comming-
Connected to the target VM, address: 'javadebug', transport: 'shared memory'

Usage:
 <bill.jpeg>

Where:
bucketName - The name of the Amazon S3 bucket that contains the document.

```
docName - The document name (must be an image, i.e., book.png).
```

Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'javadebug', transport: 'shared memory'

Process finished with exit code 1

Please help

I am trying a aws java program to analyze the document.

Comment: Please try suggestions from similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37781970/disconnected-from-the-target-vm-address-127-0-0-162535-transport-socket